# POST method's response is doing nothing . cant res.json() nor res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, response

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const JWT_SECRET = require('../../config/keys').JWT_SECRET;
const userModel = require('../../models/User');

const postChangePassword = async (req, res) => {
    let isChanged = true;
    const { token, newPassword } = req.body;

    try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
        const _id = verified.id;
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 8);
        await userModel.updateOne({ _id }, { $set: { password: hashedPassword } });
    } catch (error) {
        isChanged = false;

        console.log(error);
    }

    res.render('change-password', { isChanged });
    console.log('wow');
};

module.exports = postChangePassword;
```

My controller is like that for using `app.post("/change-password", postChangePassword)`. But res render is unresponsive. It does not giving error but it's not working even I try res.json or redirect. The request is coming from fetch() method another in the app and the other codes is working well except res.something.

And here is my POST code where request comes from

```html
  <script>


        async function postToken(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

            const result = await fetch('/authUser/change-password', {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',

                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },

                body: JSON.stringify({

                    newPassword: password,
                    token: token
                }),

            })
        }

        const form = document.getElementById('form')
        form.addEventListener('submit', postToken)
    </script>
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, do not use fetch options unless they are necessary AND you understand what they do. You are rendering a view, but your POST request accepts only JSON. Start simple, get things to work, then gradually complicate things until something breaks. Also: you're doing an ajax / fetch request. This happens in the background, it will not make the browser navigate to the result/url. This mechanism is supposed to be used to communicate with the server in the background, while staying on the current page.

Comment: To alter or add to a form's data, use an onsubmit handler and hidden inputs instead.

Comment: Thx for your answer but how can i set localStorage to JWT token while not using fetch request.There is no problem to take request , the problem is response part .The response object is not working but the user is update succesfully

Comment: Again: the request is made successfully, but you are discarding the server's reply (more specifically: the reponse object you're storing in `result`). You are using `fetch` but it's the wrong tool for this job. I already told you exactly what you need to do. Give me a sec and I'll show some example code.

Comment: This is all you need: https://jsfiddle.net/egk3afwj/ (and maybe a submit button)

Comment: Thx I will try that

Comment: I tried your solution but when i submit the form the token is not available in the request json ````  <script>


        const postToken = () => {
            this.token.value = localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))






        const form = document.getElementById('form')
        form.addEventListener('submit', postToken)


    </script>```

Comment: Right, the form data is sent as URL encoded; you need to set up express to [parse that](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I had already done that parsing operation before.I think the problem was the arrow function since the scope is different than the default "function" keyword.Do you know why arrow function was not working with "this" keyword at my first try. Now I changed the arrow function to norma function like that. 
        function postToken() {
            this.token.value = localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
Everything is fine now.

Comment: Yeah, an arrow function has a specific purpose, it's not a shortcut. For event handlers, always use the `function` keyword.

Comment: I am appreciate for your help